# preventing php template from being included again

Tags: php

A randomized template is included in the root page each time the page gets **reloaded**.  How can i **prevent** the same template from being included again?

```
   <?php
      $templates= array("template1.php","template2.php","template3.php");
      $Randomize_templates = $templates[array_rand($templates,1)];
      include  $Randomize_templates;
    ?>
```

For example:
if `template1.php` has been already included, remove that from array.

```
$templates= array("template2.php","template3.php");
```

Comment: Have you tried http://php.net/manual/es/function.include-once.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can do this

1. Shuffle original array
2. save it in session for the current user
3. pop out first template from session each time the user visit the page
4. when the array is empty, shuffle it and reload again.

And that's a code example

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['templates']) || empty($_SESSION['templates'])) {
  $templates = array("t1.php","t2.php","t3.php");
  shuffle($templates); // templates are shuffled in place
  $_SESSION['templates'] = $templates;
}

// or array_pop that should be faster if you have a huge amount of templates
$currentTemplate = array_shift($_SESSION['templates']);
```

This should be included every time you need to perform this kind of operation

Important: be sure that your session is started, otherwise start it explicitly with `session_start()`

Comment: @GragasIncoming I had a typo in hit, take a look to the code right now

Comment: @GragasIncoming `array_shift` does the job

Comment: yeah your code is correct. I have an issue with my code and it is popping 2-2 elements from the array for some reason

Answer (score 0):

At the moment every page reload resets the templates array to its original state with all the templates.

You could solve that, by using a session and session variable `$_SESSION['templates']`, setting the array initially (if it's empty `if (empty($_SESSION['templates'])){$_SESSION['templates']= array("template1.php","template2.php","template3.php");}`) and editing the session variable as your user navigates though your site.
An alternative to this solution would be to use a Database or text file, but the Session itself would be most comfortable.

Just take into account what could happen, if a user navigates more times within your site than the amount of available templates.